# Debian video-streaming server

Tags: debian, video-streaming, rtmp

I'm interested in setting up a server to which I can send a video stream and then it will re-broadcast it to save my bandwidth (Don't worry, got unlimited on the server).

I haven't been able to find any software for Debian or any other Linux-based system, and I do not have a desktop environment installed on it.

Comment: If you are re-broadcasting locally then look up 'multicast'.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Red5 server](http://www.red5.org/) or the [Adobe Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-family.html), if you want to go the premium route.

These will allow you to publish and watch streams from a server location.